# How to get previous day name in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

Please help me get previous day's name using `c#`. I tried this one but its not working.

```
string yesterday-name = System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek(-1).ToString();
```

Comment: "did not work for me" is not a helpful error report. `What` does not work? What is the output in your case? Is there an exception?

Comment: `yesterday-name` - is this possible?

Comment: no it's not. I've changed my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `string yesterdayname = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek.ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

Your present syntax is wrong `Now.DayOfWeek(-1)` and that is why it is not working for you. You can try

```
//default locale
string yesterdayname = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek.ToString();
//localized version
string yesterdayname = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dddd");
```